# Applying Group on Rows in Excell SpreadSheet and get total of them

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I create an applictaion that creat excel file using OpenXML 
At one of spreadsheets I want to group rows and get total of values of specific (colomn in row)

```
**Student           Subject       Score**
Ahmed                 A          20
Ahmed                 B           15
Ahmed                 C           15
Ahmed Total                      50
Aly                 A            10
Aly                 B            20
Aly                 C            10
Aly Total                        40
Grand Total                      90
```

I need to group scores for each student to get his score 
 then group all scores to get grand total and the style of grouping is the same with style in Ribbon in Excel

I found class GroupItems but I haven't any tutorial for it

How can I do it using OpenXMl + C#

Answer (score 0):

found this example for grouping columns and rows http://openxmldeveloper.org/discussions/formats/f/14/p/312/721.aspx#721, not  [yet] tested it.

Row grouping is achieved using `outlineLevelRow="1"`.

Totals can be done using formulas within the cells.